# Umlauts are not escaped (Chameleon / i18n)

Tags: pyramid, chameleon

I developed a Pyramid application with Chameleon templates. I use the i18n module of Chameleon to access the gettext based translation mechanism. In my translated .po files I have German umlauts. These umlauts are not escaped somewhere and directly appear in the browser while other characters like `&` are transformed to `&amp;`

As a workaround I escaped all special characters in the `.po` file. Is there a better / automatic way?

Comment: Why do you need the umlauts escaped? UTF-8 encoded HTML does not *have* to use entities to represent them. `&` on the other hand *must* be escaped in HTML.

Comment: hmm good point. thanks for the hint.